# {"type":"error","text":"Sorry Request must be Ajax POST"}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know why I'm still getting that error. I've been trying to remove the error, but I still receiving it. I need help because I ran out of choices. What I'm doing wrong? What I have to do?

This is my html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                        
                        <div class="contact">
                            <form id='contacts_form' method="post" action="contacts.php">
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <input type="submit" class="form_submit" value="Send Message" />
                                </div>
                                <div id="contact_results"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

This is my jQuery

```
    (function($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        /*PRELOADER JS*/
        $(window).load(function() { 
            $('.status').fadeOut();
            $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
        }); 
        /*END PRELOADER JS*/

        /*START MENU JS*/
        $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(e){
            var anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
            }, 1500);
            e.preventDefault();
        });     

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.menu-top').addClass('menu-shrink');
            } else {
            $('.menu-top').removeClass('menu-shrink');
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
        if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
            $(this).collapse('hide');
        }
        });             
        /*END MENU JS*/ 

        /*START TESTIMONIAL JS*/
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval:5000,
            pause:'false',
        });
        /*END TESTIMONIAL JS*/

        /*START PARTNER LOGO*/
        $('.partner').owlCarousel({
          autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
          items : 4,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
        });
        /*END PARTNER LOGO*/        

        $("#form_submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parents('form');
            form.find('.form-control').removeClass('error');
            form.find('.error_block').remove();
            var post_data;
            var errors = formValidation(form),
                output;
            if( Object.keys(errors).length > 0 ) {
                showErrors(form, errors);
            } else {
                if(form.attr('id') == 'contacts_form') {
                    post_data = {
                        'name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                        'email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                        'message'  : $('input[name=message]').val()
                    };

                    //Ajax post data to server
                    jQuery.post('contacts.php', post_data, function(response){
                        if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message
                            output = '<div class="error_block">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        } else{
                            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                            //reset values in all input fields
                            $("#contacts_form .form-control").val('');
                        }
                        form.find('.form_row').slideUp();
                        form.find("#contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                    }, 'json');
                } else {
                    post_data = {
                        'subscribe_email': $('input[name=subscribe_email]').val(),
                    };

                    jQuery.post('subscribe.php', post_data, function(response){

                        output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        //reset values in all input fields
                        $("#contacts_form .form_item").val('');
                        form.find('.form_inner').slideUp();
                        form.find("#form_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                    }, 'json');
                }

            }
            return false;
        });
    });     

    /*START WOW ANIMATION JS*/
      new WOW().init(); 
    /*END WOW ANIMATION JS*/                
    })(jQuery);
```

This is my php

```
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( 
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); 
    }


    $name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message   = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$name."\r\nEmail : ".$email;


    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail1 = @mail($to_email1, $name, $message_body, $headers);
    $send_mail2 = @mail($to_email2, $name, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail1 || !$send_mail2)
    {

        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$name .'! Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
     ?>
```

Comment: can you confirm your request headers include `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: First time using php... which request? which headers?

Comment: nothing to do with PHP in my comment :p `jQuery.post` - use the browser developer tools to check what headers are being sent

Comment: `!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest'`  contains ambiguity.

Comment: @JaromandaX what information about headers I need?

Comment: I asked if you can see `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` request header ... a simple yes or no would be sufficient :p

Comment: then.. no. @JaromandaX

Comment: well, that's right (I did not see the `!=` for some reason) ...

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that if it's not set and it's not equal to xmlhttprequest to fail. You need to say OR instead of AND

```
if(
   false === isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || 
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'
) {
    // you code
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of the `$_SERVER` variable. `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email1       = "email1";
    $to_email2       = "email2";

Comment: that's not the output of `$_SERVER` it's going to be quite lengthy. Add it to your question please.

Comment: this is the output I receive:{“type”:“error”,“text”:“Sorry Request must be Ajax POST”}

Comment: yea ... so add a `var_dump($_SERVER)` before this message so it outputs that.

Comment: Well you you want you can post just the line that shows HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

Comment: I have HTTP_X_HTTP_PROTO , HTTP_X_LOG , HTTP_X_REAL_IP ... nothing about HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

Comment: Well that explains why you're getting that message. Is it really necessary to ensure it came via ajax? It's checking to make sure this header is set, and it's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                        
                    <div class="contact">
                        <form id='contacts_form' method="post" action="contacts" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
                            <div class="field-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="field-group">
                                <input type="submit" id="form_submit" class="form_submit" value="Send Message" />
                            </div>
                            <div id="contact_results"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/0.1.12/wow.min.js"></script>    
  <script>new WOW().init();</script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  (function($) {
   'use strict';

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    /*PRELOADER JS*/
    $(window).on('load',function() { 
        $('.status').fadeOut();
        $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
    }); 
    /*END PRELOADER JS*/

    /*START MENU JS*/
    $('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(e){
        var anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
        }, 1500);
        e.preventDefault();
    });     

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.menu-top').addClass('menu-shrink');
        } else {
        $('.menu-top').removeClass('menu-shrink');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
    });             
    /*END MENU JS*/ 

    /*START TESTIMONIAL JS*/
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval:5000,
        pause:'false',
    });
    /*END TESTIMONIAL JS*/

    /*START PARTNER LOGO*/
    $('.partner').owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
    });
    /*END PARTNER LOGO*/  



    $("#form_submit").click(function(e){
        //alert('ok');
        var output;
        //e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        form.find('.form-control').removeClass('error');
        form.find('.error_block').remove();
        var post_data;

            if(form.attr('id') == 'contacts_form') {
                post_data = {
                    'name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                    'email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'message'  : $('input[name=message]').val()
                };

                //Ajax post data to server
                jQuery.post('http://localhost/stackoverflow/contacts', post_data, function(response){
                    if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message
                        output = '<div class="error_block">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    } else{
                        output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        //reset values in all input fields
                        $("#contacts_form .form-control").val('');
                    }
                    form.find('.form_row').slideUp();
                    form.find("#contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }, 'json');
            } else {
                post_data = {
                    'subscribe_email': $('input[name=subscribe_email]').val(),
                };

                jQuery.post('subscribe.php', post_data, function(response){

                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $("#contacts_form .form_item").val('');
                    form.find('.form_inner').slideUp();
                    form.find("#form_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                }, 'json');
            }

        //}
        return false;
    });
});     

/*START WOW ANIMATION JS*/
  new WOW().init(); 
/*END WOW ANIMATION JS*/                
})(jQuery);
```